# Name for nearly linear (line-shaped) subgraph of a graph

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

Given a graph, it's straightforward to define a "linear" or line-shaped subgraph: a connected subgraph with two ends which are nodes of degree one, and intermediate nodes of degree two. And maybe a single point as a degenerate variant.

Now add new edges to nodes outside of the subgraph to it. The result is "nearly" a "linear" graph, maybe one could call it 1-linear: If one removes those edges again, the result is a "linear" graph.

And so on for 2-linear etc.

Is this a known concept? Is there some generally accepted terminology for this?

Examples, subgraphs only:

```
1 -- 2 -- 3 -- 4
```

is linear.

```
A         B
|         |
1 -- 2 -- 3 -- 4 -- E
|    |
C    D
```

is "1-linear", if you remove edges to A..E, you end up with a linear "spine".

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the construction in the second paragraph, can you give a concrete example? Is this a reasonable starting point for you: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_graph ?

Comment: @perpetuallyconfused added examples. "Path graph" or "linear graph" looks good as terminology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And with the link to Wikipedia provided by @perpetuallyconfused I can answer my own question:

There is indeed the name "linear graph" or "path graph", and what I called "1-linear" is a [Caterpillar Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caterpillar_tree). What I called "2-linear" seems to be a Lobster Tree or [Lobster Graph](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LobsterGraph.html).

There are also generalizations called [K-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-tree), but they look a bit different than what I had in mind.

Though in the application where this came up the extended graphs are not necessarily trees, but at least this points me in the right direction.